# Java iterator over an empty collection of a parameterized type

Tags: java, collections, iterator

In Java, I need to return an Iterator from my method.  My data comes from another object which usually can give me an iterator so I can just return that, but in some circumstances the underlying data is null.  For consistency, I want to return an "empty" iterator in that case so my callers don't have to test for null.

I wanted to write something like:

```
public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
   if (underlyingData != null) {
      return underlyingData.iterator();  // works
   } else {
      return Collections.emptyList().iterator();  // compiler error
   }
}
```

But the Java compiler complains about the returning `Iterator<Object>` instead of `Iterator<Foo>`.  Casting to `(Iterator<Foo>)` doesn't work either.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can get an empty list of type Foo through the following syntax:

```
return Collections.<Foo>emptyList().iterator();
```

Comment: I have just discovered that sometimes trying to be quick slows you down. I had written up an empty Iterator<Foo> implementation and returned here to find I'd been off on a bunny trail. +1

Comment: In Java 1.7 Collections API was extended with `Collections.emptyIterator()`.

Answer (score 37):

Java 7 has been out for a long time now. Unless you're developing for a previous Java version, you would return an empty iterator like this:

```
return Collections.emptyIterator();
```

Comment: You can also parameterize your empty iterator: `Collections.<Integer> emptyIterator()`

Answer (score 9):

I'd go more along the lines of

```
public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
    if (underlyingData == null)
        return Collections.<Foo> emptyList().iterator();
    return underlyingData.iterator();
}
```

Just, handle the special case and return, then handle the normal case.  But my main point is that you can avoid the assignment with

```
Collections.<Foo> emptyList().iterator();
```

Comment: IMO, null and non-null are equally special in this case. else is clearer here.

Comment: You're entitled to YO, of course, but to me it seems as if this class is treating all lists, including the empty list, as if (this class) were the list - that is normal flow, to me - but it is treating null specially - as if it were the empty list, which it is not.  It is delegating to underlyingData normally, and manufacturing something special when it can't.

Comment: @DJClayworth, you're entitled to YO, as well.  I consider unnecessary braces to be codejunk. http://www.slideshare.net/carlmanaster/codejunk-ignitesd

Answer (score 4):

The annoyance of `Collections.<Foo>emptyList().iterator()` is the main reason we provide `Iterators.emptyIterator()` in [google-collections](http://google-collections.googlecode.com). No type parameter needed, in cases like yours.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this shows that Java type inference doesn't work in every case and that the ternary operator is not always equivalent to the apparently equivalent if-else construct.

I also want to state **avoid `null`**. Also avoid passing `Iterator`s about, because they have strange stateful behaviour (prefer `Iterable`). However, assuming you have a legitimate, non-premature reason for doing this, my preferred way of writing it would be

```
public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
    return getUnderlyingData().iterator();
}
private List<Foo> getUnderlyingData() {
    if (underlyingData == null) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } else {
        return underlyingData;
    }
}
```

IMO, it's better not to insert the inferable type information if it can be inferred (even if it makes your code longer).

You are almost certainly going to do it more than once, so insert a `getUnderlyingData` method instead of just declaring a local variable.

You are calling `iterator` on both results, so do not repeat yourself.

Comment: +1 for the DRY win from only calling iterator() from one place. I wonder if this kind of solution could be moved to where underlyingData is modified - this would be DRYest of all I think.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I figured it out.  You need to use an assignment so that the compiler can figure out the parameterized type.

```
public Iterator<Foo> iterator() {
   if (underlyingData != null) {
      return underlyingData.iterator();
   } else {
      List<Foo> empty = Collections.emptyList();  // param type inference
      return empty.iterator();
   }
}
```

Comment: Wow, Alex B answered even before I could type in my solution.  I was missing the syntax for the parameterized type returned by emptyList().  The assignment works, but the one liner is even better.

Answer (score 0):

```
public  final class EmptyIterator{

    public static Iterator iterator(){
        return new Empty();
    }

    private static class Empty implements Iterator {
        public boolean hasNext(){
            return false;
        }
        public Object next(){
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        public void remove(){
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a built in iterator that does the same: `Collections.emptyIterator();`.