# Use of emptyIterator in java

Tags: java, iterator

Can anyone let me know what is the real time use of an Empty Iterator in java? I'm curious to know why is it needed?
things like,

```
 1.  public static <T> Iterator<T> emptyIterator()
 2.  public static <T> ListIterator<T> emptyListIterator()
 3.  public static final <T> Set<T> emptySet(), etc..
```

source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#emptyIterator()

Comment: Sorry the link mentioned as 'possible duplicate of' does not answer my question or may be I couldn't understand the answer. Can someone elaborate on - at what scenario they are needed?

Comment: The question answers it actually: `I want to return an "empty" iterator in that case so my callers don't have to test for null` :)

Comment: ok thanks :) unknowingly I answered to this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/821536/java-iterator-over-an-empty-collection-of-a-parameterized-type) question in the name of a New Question! So this question can be tagged as a duplicate answer. not as a duplicate question. Just Kidding, no offense.

Comment: It's not a bad question at all.  You can very much post that as an answer here.  I was just trying to keep consistent with the website is all.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use an empty iterator in cases where an API that you implement requires an iterator, but some of your code's logic can yield no items in the result. In that case, instead of returning a `null`, you return an empty iterator. You can also use an empty iterator to save some memory and for testing purposes.

Here is some example code that prevents returning `null` and saves some memory at the same time:

```
class LazyObjectInitialization {

   private Collection<String> items; 

   public final Iterator<String> items() {

      if(items == null || items.isEmpty()) {
         return Collections.emptyIterator(); 
      }

      return items.iterator();
   }

   public final add(String item) { 

      if(items == null) {
         items = new ArrayList<>();
      }

      items.add(item);
   }
}
```

In the above class, the field `items` is not initialized until an element is added. So to provide expected behavior in method `items()` we return an empty iterator. The benefit from this are as follow:

- Smaller memory consumption

  - The class allocates memory only when it is really needed.
- Smaller memory mutation

  - Until we add something to the object, we never create a new instance of the iterator.
- We never return `null`.